# Is it good to use await before dispatch hooks in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, redux

I have a situation where i want to run 2 dispatch events one after another.
There is no dependancy between 2.

Can i run something like below?

```
await dispatch(firstEvent)
dispatch(secondEvent)
```

I want to run secondEvent only after the first one.

Is there any better approach to call this other than using await?
I have tried using callback from firstevent and all. ( Please suggest best practiced )

Answer (score 1):

Dispatch is synchronous, so the await keyword gets you nothing here.
You could use the [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) library to get the async flow you're looking for.